# Perforce P4v: How to find file with a list of file to be find?

Tags: perforce, p4v

Is there a way or command to be use to find files using a list of files to be find in a directory?
e.g.

find the following files: 

text1.sql

text2.sql

text3.sql

text4.sql

text5.sql

text6.sql

Search in: c:\archive...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but try the following:

1. Search > Find File...
2. Enter the directory under "Search in:"
3. Enter the name of the file you are looking for under "Name contains:"
4. Click on Find.

I'm using the P4V client version 2012.1

Answer (score 1):

Just putting out there that Saulo's answer is correct, however that Rev. Perforce Visual Client/NTX86/2008.2/188141 doesn't support it.  So you probably need to upgrade if you don't have the menu option (as I had to).